# how to load sql dump using mysql_query in php

Tags: php, mysql

To install a cms i have a form in which i ask user to enter a database name he wants the script to make tables into. After that i have my only three cms tables.

i am trying to read that `dump.sql` file using the `file = get_file_contents(dump.sql)` and then `mysql_query($file);`
but nothing is happening please suggest or help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_query` can not run multiple queries in once.

you can try [mysqli:multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function

OR

There is another way to do this with [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and mysql command.

You can execute the mysql command to store the tables in database using the exec function of php.

That will be something like this

```
$Command = "mysql -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database} < {$BackupFile}";
exec($Command);
```

Comment: Thanks i am using multi_query() otherwise i had to fix path to mysql in windows for exec to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a tricky solution but you can explode the whole sql file from ";" characters if you dont have data containing ; characters in it. If so it will be hard to escape them first.

For example:

```
$lines = file_get_contents("your_sql_dump");
$lines = explode(";", $dumpSql);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    mysql_query($line, $conn);
}
```